# Using ojdbc5 and ojdbc8 driver in the same application with java11+

Tags: java, jdbc, java-9, urlclassloader

In my program I have to connect to several databases. For certain reasons **I have to use several different ojdbc drivers, e.g. ojdbc5.jar, ojdbc8.jar,** etc. Nothing can be changed about that.
With Java 8 it works like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JdbcMain {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final File driverOne = new File("C:\\workspace\\lib\\ojdbc5.jar");
    final File driverTwo = new File("C:\\workspace\\lib\\ojdbc8.jar");

    getJDBCForDriver(driverOne);
    getJDBCForDriver(driverTwo);
}

private static void getJDBCForDriver(final File jdbcDriverFile) throws Exception {
    final URL url = jdbcDriverFile.toURI().toURL();
    final URL[] array = new URL[] {url};
    final URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(array, null);
    final Class driverClass = ucl.loadClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    final Driver driver = (Driver) driverClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); 

    final Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("user", "myUser");
    prop.put("password", "myPassword");
    try (final Connection connection = driver.connect("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", prop)) {
        final DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
        final int jdbcMajorVersion = metaData.getJDBCMajorVersion();
        final int jdbcMinorVersion = metaData.getJDBCMinorVersion();
        System.out.println("JDBC Version for File " + jdbcDriverFile.getName() + ": " + jdbcMajorVersion + "." + jdbcMinorVersion);
    }
}
}
```

The output for Java 8 is:

```
JDBC Version for File ojdbc5.jar: 11.1
JDBC Version for File ojdbc8.jar: 4.2
```

**Since Java 11 (or 9), however, this no longer works.** The following error occurs here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at zzzz_Jdbc.JdbcMain.getJDBCForDriver(JdbcMain.java:26)
    at zzzz_Jdbc.JdbcMain.main(JdbcMain.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Driver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 12 more
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Have you modularized your application? If so, have you added a `requires java.sql` to your `module-info.java`? Please provide a [mre] to reproduce this.

Comment: My Application is not modularized. I have provided an example.

Comment: Why use a JDBC driver intended for Java 1.5 with Java 11? You write "nothing can be done about that", but this sounds like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) to me. You should find out _why_ you think you need to use an outdated (and deprecated) driver to begin with

Comment: We have to connect to many different databases. We have found that some driver versions do not work with some database versions. Therefore we want to be able to define which driver should be used for which database connection.